# "give something to someone as I had been given"?

Tags: expressions, phrases

Say I received much love from the community as I grow up and now wish to give such love to younglings in the community. Is it correct/natural to say "I give love to them as I had been given"?

What could be some other common phrases expressing the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "I give love to them as I had been given" is a perfecty fine sentence. Depending on your situation, you can also say "I will give love to them as I had been given" if you're trying to show that you will give love to them in the future tense.

You can also say, and it might be even more natural, "I will give them love like I had been given." (future) or "I give them love like I had been given." Using "like" sounds even more natural, especially when worded like this.

Comment: awesome, thank you for your comment and suggestions!

Comment: I think that "have been given" works better than using "had".

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote would be understood but sounds very formal.

In ordinary conversation you might rather write,

> I give as much love to them as I was given

Or, you might use an even more informal phrase and say,

> I was given much love as a child and now I want to *pay it forward*.